# ios app reading html data out of database using json

Tags: html, ios, database

I have a database in the cloud which I am reading data from just fine.  One of the fields contains html table info  with the html tags in it.  I want to display this in an ios app.

How do I and what do I read this data into in the ios app?  A text view? or what and will it handle the html tags in the text and display the data as a table?

Answer (score 0):

Use [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and load your html as a string into it.